# Procedural Generation: dividing a map into multiple areas

Tags: procedural-generation

I am creating a world generator (like in Minecraft). I am using Perlin noise to generate the elevation map. But I want to divide my map into areas (or biomes).

I can divide the map into equal polygons, but I am looking for a more random way.

My map is pixelated (composed of blocks). Every pixel has x and y coordinates.

Example:
[image: Example map]

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is generating additional noise maps for things like temperature, humidity and maybe even more(the more different biomes you have the more important it will be to have more different parameters to differentiate them).

Then you assign each biome you have a value for each of those parameters and you also need to add some height limit(so your engine won't create a forest under water or similar stupid things).

Then for each point on the map you choose the closest biome in terms of temperature, humidity, …

That's the basic concept. Depending on your noisemaps that will generate a random-looking pattern and as a bonus also keeping realism(biomes of similar temperature and humidity are close to each other)

Here are some further tips for the actual implementation:

1. Make sure the temperature and humidity maps have much lower frequencies than the heigh map, so biomes don't get too small.
2. I suggest also adding a low-frequency part, so the transition is not so smooth.
3. If you want to add a more natural transition between biomes, you can choose randomly if two biomes are similarly good in terms of the parameters.